# Emoji Selector Empty

Tags: kde, emoji

After deleting (by error) many packages, I came to notice that most of my emojis don't appear. In the "Emoji Selector", I have 4 emojis in the "recent" tab, but none in the "search" and the "all" ones.

**I tried:**
Installing noto-coloremoji-fonts, kirigami2-dev and plasma-framework
Changing locals
Check if noto is installed with `apt list --installed | grep -i emoji`. Output: `fonts-noto-color-emoji/stable,stable,now 0~20200916-1 all [installed]`
Opening ibus-ui-emojier-plasma on terminal. Found an error `could not find ibus emoji dictionaries. "ibus/dicts/emoji-en.dict"`. However, it still opens

I use MX Linux (Debian) KDE Plasma, if it helps at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by reinstalling the *gnome-icon-theme* package

Comment: For me this doesn't help, but in my case on Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE - installing the `ibus-data` package resolves the problem: `sudo apt install ibus-data`